# How to prevent recreating a new subview when reenter a navigationlink?

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

I have a navigationview which contains only one navigationlink. The destination view of the link contains a subview. My problem is every time I reenter the navigationlink, it won't cause the reinit of the destination view, but cause the reinit and the recreate of the subview and I just lose the state of the subview. There must be a way to prevent the recreate of the subview but I have found nothing useful so far. Below is the code:(The func IncNum is aimed to check if the state is stored.)
//NavigationView
import SwiftUI

```
struct MainPagePLView: View {

init(){
    print("init mainpageview")
}

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: TipsPLView().equatable()){
            HStack{
                Text("LinkToSubView")
            }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
    .onAppear(){
        print("mainpageview onappears")
    }.onDisappear(){
        print("mainpageview disappears")
    }
}
}

//Destination View
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TipsPLView : View,Identifiable,Equatable
{
var id = UUID()

static func == (lhs: TipsPLView, rhs: TipsPLView) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

init(){
    print("init TipsPLView")
}
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        List{
            
Section(header:Text("TipsPLView").font(.system(size:20)).foregroundColor(.yellow)){
                SubView().equatable()
}
}.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())}
}
}

//SubView
struct SubView:View,Identifiable,Equatable
{
static func == (lhs: SubView, rhs: SubView) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}

@State var id = UUID()
@State var num = 0

init(){
    print("Init SubView")
}
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Button(action:{IncNum()}){
            Text("\(num)")
        }
    }
}
func IncNum(){
    num+=1
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Recreation will be always (even for equability check) - if you need persistency use `AppStorage`

Comment: @Asperi But why does the destination view(TipsPLView) not get recreated and just the subview get recreated?

Comment: This is common behavior of any sort of Navigation. If you navigate away, it's expected that you're "Done" with that view and it is Discarded appropriately. If this weren't the case then we'd have so much memory usage being chewed up by views that are no longer present. The solution is as Asperi stated, `@AppStorage` or some other form of storage, database, API, etc...

Comment: SwiftUI views are designed to be lightweight descriptions of your user interface, and have the potential to be created or destroyed as the SwiftUI rendering system needs. Can I ask what the exact problem you're trying to solve is? There may well be a more SwiftUI-style way of accomplishing something, rather than trying to force SwiftUI to work in ways that it's not comfortable with…

Comment: @xTwisteDx Yes, that makes sense. But the destination view(TipsPLView) is not discarded and recreated when I leave it and reenter it. Only the subview of the destination view gets discarded and recreated. This is confusing. It looks like I should unwrap the content of the subview into the parent view then nothing will be discarded. But when the parent view is complex, it is supposed to be split into different subviews for a clearer structure.

Comment: @ScottMatthewman my main task is when I tap into the navigationlink, I will be rendered with a list of songs and they can be played in a loop. And I have to keep the track of the song currently played and highlight it's row in the list. So my problem is due to the subview gets recreated every time I reenter it, I can't keep states of the play list.

Comment: @ScottMatthewman By reading you, Asperi and xTwisteDx's comments I realize that I should use some forms of storage like AppStorage to keep states. But I am still confused that if the view is designed to be discarded when I navigate away, why is the the destination view(TipsPLView) not discarded and recreated? Anyway I think I can solve the problem now, thanks for your help!